# Howell form for symmetric matrices modulo N

Tags: modular-arithmetic, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I am looking at a problem of the type
$A^P\equiv A\pmod N$,
where A is a square symmetric integer matrix, and I want to find the minimum value of the power $P$. It seems that the [Howell form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howell_normal_form) of $A$ could give some insight into the problem but I am not sure how to calculate it. An algorithm is described in [Fast Algorithms for Linear Algebra Modulo N](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eastorjoh/esa.pdf) but it is a bit heavy to figure out an implementation from that. Mathematica has a RowReduce function that allows a value for the modulo but it can't calculate the result of any of the two examples listed in the two references.